# Drag and drop elements inside a cavas that is inside a ScrollViewer on touch screen

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, scrollview

I have a ScrollViewer inside which I have some expanders and of the Expander's content has a Canvas. I am drawing two rectangles on the Canvas which are Thumb controls that can be dragged around. Problem is, whenever I press on the rectangles and try to drag, it somehow assumes that I want to scroll the entire page and the Drag never happens. How can I solve this problem inside the ScrollViewer.

There is a property called `CanBeScrollAnchor`which I saw on MSDN for UWP that says the property is used for (Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the UIElement can be a candidate for scroll anchoring.). But setting that to false doesn't help. (I am adding the WPF tag because the concept is the same). Please help

Edit: This issue occurs only on the touch screen.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<uwpControls:Expander>
<!--Some Content-->
</uwpControls:Expander>

<uwpControls:Expander HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ToggleButtonFullWidthHeader}"
                              Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemBackgroundBrush}" Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Header="DragDrop">

                    <Grid x:Name="gridBarImagePanel" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">

                        <uwpControls:ImageEx x:Name="BarCodeImage" IsCacheEnabled="True" Source="..\SampleImage\demo.png" 
                                 Stretch="UniformToFill" />

                        <Canvas x:Name="cnvBarCodeImage" Canvas.ZIndex="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </uwpControls:Expander>

</StackPanel> 
</ScrollViewer>
```

In the code behind, I am calling this method to draw two Thumb controls on the Canvas dynamically.

```
public sealed partial class SomeControl:Page
{
event Action<Thumb, double, double> ChangeDimensions;

public void OnSomeButtonClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
 //TEST(Remove this)
                dimensions.Add(new Dimensions()
                {
                    Height = 80,
                    Width = 150,
                    left = 250,
                    Top = 40,
                    BorderColor = BrushCollection[0],
                    MaxLeftPossible = null,
                    MaxTopPossible = null,//280
                    MaxRightPossible = null,
                    MaxBottomPossible = null,
                });
                dimensions.Add(new Dimensions()
                {
                    Height = 80,
                    Width = 150,
                    left = 250,
                    Top = 150,
                    BorderColor = BrushCollection[1],
                    MaxLeftPossible = null,
                    MaxTopPossible = null,//280
                    MaxRightPossible = null,
                    MaxBottomPossible = null,
                });
                //CreateUIShapes(SelectedRowItem.WindowLocations.Count, dimensions);
                CreateUIShapes(2, dimensions);

}
       private void CreateUIShapes(int numberOfWindows, List<Dimensions> dimensions)
            {
                Thumb th = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWindows; i++)
                {
                    th = new Thumb();
                    th.Name = string.Format("{0}{1}", "Thumb", i + 1);
                    var item = dimensions[i];
                    th.Width = item.Width;
                    th.Height = item.Height;
                    th.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
                    th.BorderBrush = item.BorderColor;
                    th.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
                    th.DragDelta += (sender, e) => Th_DragDelta(sender, e, dimensions);
                    th.DragCompleted += (sender, e) => Th_DragCompleted(sender, e);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(th, CheckAndGetItemToLeft(item.left, i));
                    Canvas.SetTop(th, CheckAndGetItemTotop(item.Top, i));
                    cnvBarCodeImage.Children.Add(th);
                }
            }

//This is the code to drag and drop.    
     private void Th_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e, List<Dimensions> LimitedWindowMovements)
        {
            var SelectedDraggableThumb = sender as Thumb;
            double left = (Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb) >= 0) ? Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb) : 0;
            double top = (Canvas.GetTop(SelectedDraggableThumb) >= 0) ? Canvas.GetTop(SelectedDraggableThumb) : 0;

            if (ChkDualMode.IsChecked == true)
            {
                var OtherDraggableThumbs = cnvBarCodeImage.Children.OfType<Thumb>().Where(x => x != SelectedDraggableThumb);

                var maxTopSelected = LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxTopPossible == null ? 1 : LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxTopPossible;
                var maxBottomSelected = LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxBottomPossible == null ? BarCodeImage.ActualHeight - SelectedDraggableThumb.ActualHeight : LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxBottomPossible;
                var maxLeftSelected = LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxLeftPossible == null ? 0 : LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxLeftPossible;
                var maxRightSelected = LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxRightPossible == null ? BarCodeImage.ActualWidth - SelectedDraggableThumb.Width : LimitedWindowMovements[0].MaxRightPossible;
                //Boundry case for top->Current element.
                //Don't allow further up.

                if (top < maxTopSelected) //Hardcoding for now. top < 1 original.
                {
                    if (e.VerticalChange <= 1)
                    {
                        ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //Boundry case for bottom->Current element.
                //Don't allow further down.
                //Canvas.GetTop(SelectedDraggableThumb) >= BarCodeImage.ActualHeight - SelectedDraggableThumb.ActualHeight original.
                else if (Canvas.GetTop(SelectedDraggableThumb) >= maxBottomSelected)
                {
                    if (e.VerticalChange > 0)
                    {
                        ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //Boundry case for left->Current element.
                //Don't allow further left.
                //Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb) <= 0 original.
                else if (Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb) <= maxLeftSelected)
                {
                    if (e.HorizontalChange <= 1)
                    {
                        ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //Boundry case for left->Current element.
                //Don't allow further right.
                //Math.Round(Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb), 1) >= BarCodeImage.ActualWidth - SelectedDraggableThumb.Width original.
                else if (Math.Round(Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb), 1) >= maxRightSelected)
                {
                    if (e.HorizontalChange >= 0)
                    {
                        ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //There may be n number of windows.
                foreach (var item in OtherDraggableThumbs)
                {
                    //Boundry case for the other thumb moving up.
                    //Don't allow further up.
                    //var OtherTop = Canvas.GetTop(item); original
                    var OtherTop = Canvas.GetTop(item);
                    if (OtherTop < maxTopSelected)
                    {
                        if (e.VerticalChange <= 1)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    //Boundry case for the other thumb moving bottom
                    //Don't allow further bottom.
                    //BarCodeImage.ActualHeight - SelectedDraggableThumb.ActualHeight original
                    if (Canvas.GetTop(item) >= maxBottomSelected)
                    {

                        if (e.VerticalChange > 0)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }

                    }

                    //Boundry case for the other thumb moving left.
                    //Don't allow further left
                    //Canvas.GetLeft(item) <= 0 original
                    if (Canvas.GetLeft(item) <= maxLeftSelected)
                    {
                        if (e.HorizontalChange <= 1)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }

                    }

                    //Boundry case for the other thumb moving right.
                    //Don't allow further right
                    //Math.Round(Canvas.GetLeft(item), 1) >= BarCodeImage.ActualWidth - item.Width original
                    if (Math.Round(Canvas.GetLeft(item), 1) >= maxRightSelected)
                    {
                        if (e.HorizontalChange >= 0)
                        {
                            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                            return;
                        }
                    }


                    if (ChangeDimensions == null)
                    {
                        ChangeDimensions += BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
                    }

                }

                foreach (var item in OtherDraggableThumbs)
                {
                    ChangeDimensions?.Invoke(item, e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);
                }

            }

            left = (Canvas.GetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb) > BarCodeImage.ActualWidth - SelectedDraggableThumb.ActualWidth) ? BarCodeImage.ActualWidth - SelectedDraggableThumb.ActualWidth : left;
            top = (Canvas.GetTop(SelectedDraggableThumb) > BarCodeImage.ActualHeight - SelectedDraggableThumb.ActualHeight) ? BarCodeImage.ActualHeight - SelectedDraggableThumb.ActualHeight : top;
            Canvas.SetLeft(SelectedDraggableThumb, left + e.HorizontalChange);
            Canvas.SetTop(SelectedDraggableThumb, top + e.VerticalChange);
        }

//When one thumb moves, I want to move the other in the same direction.
  private void BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions(Thumb sender, double arg1, double arg2)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                //4025e8df
                double left = (Canvas.GetLeft(sender) > 0) ? Canvas.GetLeft(sender) : 0;
                double top = (Canvas.GetTop(sender) > 0) ? Canvas.GetTop(sender) : 0;
                left = (Canvas.GetLeft(sender) > BarCodeImage.ActualWidth - sender.ActualWidth) ? BarCodeImage.ActualWidth - sender.ActualWidth : left;
                top = (Canvas.GetTop(sender) > BarCodeImage.ActualHeight - sender.ActualHeight) ? BarCodeImage.ActualHeight - sender.ActualHeight : top;
                Canvas.SetLeft(sender, left + arg1);
                Canvas.SetTop(sender, top + arg2);
            }
        }

    private void Th_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    //Do something.
       foreach (var item in cnvBarCodeImage.Children.OfType<Thumb>())
        {
            ChangeDimensions -= BarCodeServiceView_ChangeDimensions;
        }
    }
}

 public class Dimensions
    {
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double left { get; set; }
        public double Top { get; set; }
        public Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush BorderColor { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// If no restriction needed specify null
        /// </summary>
        public double? MaxTopPossible { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// If no restriction needed specify null
        /// </summary>
        public double? MaxLeftPossible { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// If no restriction needed specify null
        /// </summary>
        public double? MaxRightPossible { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// If no restriction needed specify null
        /// </summary>
        public double? MaxBottomPossible { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You should post an MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can update my code for the drag and drop but I wanted to keep the code as short as possible so its easy to understand. Should I post any further details for the code to drag and drop etc.?

Comment: The best you can do to help yourself is to post enough code so one can simply copy/paste it and see the problem in action.

Comment: Sure. Let me update my post.

Comment: Please see the code, I updated my post.

Comment: "it somehow assumes that I want to scroll the entire page and the Drag never happens" what do you mean? And I used the code snippet, it worked well, it could drag normally. So What is your expected behavior and what the behavior you currently get? Can you show more details about this?

Comment: If there is no Scrollviewer element in the xaml it's dragging fine for me also. But when I embed stackpanel in my case, inside the Scrollviewer it never does the drag. I press on one of the thumbs on the screen and I can't drag it anywhere. I'm testing on a touch screen so I guess that's making the difference. Let me test on the desktop.

Comment: When I tested it on a touch screen, it also worked well, the thumbs can be draged. So can you provide a simple sample for us to test? In addition, what is your touch screen and what is the version of it?

Comment: Thank you it works fine for me too. My exact problem was this, in case if it helps someone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660777/uwp-how-to-prevent-page-level-scroll-bounce-effect-when-scrolling-inside-a-list. When the bounce effect happened, the Thumbs never got the focus back and was unable to drag.

Comment: So you encountered this issue when the bounce effect happened? Can the solution shared in the link solve your problem?

Comment: Yes @Faywang-MSFT thank you it solved my problem. I just made a small change but using the code shared in the link.